# Объясните почему оно не работает, элементарный  javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
   <body>
     <script language="JavaScript">
 var array = new Array();
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  array[i] = number(prompt("enter"));
document.write(array[i] + " ");
 }

      </script>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: @oknesar, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: а number() это что за функция у вас?

Comment: Это чтобы преобразовать написанное в числа, так оно будет как текст.

Comment: В JS для этого используется parseFloat().

Comment: То место, откуда был вытянут этот древний и неправильный пример, сожгите и забудьте. Пользуйтесь learn.javascript.ru

Comment: Спасибо, @alvoro, надо было с большой буквы писать.

Comment: @oknesar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

number с большой буквы напишите. Я бы делал так:

```
var array = [], // создаем массив при помощи литерала. так короче и "полезней"
i = 0, // все переменные объявляем одним оператором var на область видимости
limit = 5; // не обязательно, но может облегчить жизнь
for (; i < limit; i++) {
  array[i] = +prompt("enter"); // плюс перед значением пытается привести его к числу. опять таки не надо использовать конструктор Number, Object, Array и т.д.
};
document.write(array.join(' ')); // операции над dom-деревом "дорогие", поэтому все делаем за один раз
```